# Load a form in vb6 and receive notification when it unloads?

Tags: vb6

I want form1 to load form2 and when form2 unloads, unload form1.

I'd like to minimize coupling,.

Use case:
I launch  form1 as a semi transparent background so that form2 is easier to see.
When form2 unloads, i want form1 would unload as well. I'll be reusing this code with lots of other 'form2' type forms.

I've considered the addressof operator. Hoping for something simpler.

Comment: Well, if I remember correctly, there is an `Unload` event for `Form` classes, so you should be able to subscribe to this. Is it not possible for one form class to handle another form class's events?

Comment: @CodyGray, yep, that's exactly the idea. But I don't know how to easily have Form1 subscribe to form2's Unload event without writing code in form2's unload even handler (which I want to avoid to minimize coupling, and having to *remember* to do that everytime)

Comment: Gosh, I was hoping someone else with more recent experience in VB 6 would have come along and had their memory jogged by my comment. If I remember correctly, you can just declare a module-level variable marked `WithEvents` if you want to handle the declared object's events. Naturally, this would increase coupling between Form1 and Form2, but that seems inevitable with what you're describing. I'm not quite sure what your comment means, though: if Form1 is handling Form2's Unload event, Form2 wouldn't even need to handle its own Unload event. The handling would be in Form1's class.

Answer (score 0):

If you're displaying form2 modally, then you can unload form1 after the show method returns:

In form1, where form2 is displayed:

```
Form2.Show vbModal
Unload Me
```

Or, if you're not displaying form2 modally, then you can unload form1 in the unload event for form2:

```
Private Sub Form_Unload(Cancel As Integer)
  Unload Form1
End Sub
```